# Populate ext-js combobox with JSON

Tags: java, json, servlets, extjs

After many research, here is my question :

I try to populate a Extjs combobox with a JSON. (the Json is generated by a SQL query in a java servlet).

Here is my ext-js code :

```
function createComboBox(){

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
    autoLoad : true, 
    url : 'SourceType', 
    method : 'POST',
    fields : ['sourceName'],
    proxy : {
        type : 'memory', 
        reader : {
            type : 'json', 
            root : 'data', 
        }
    }
});

store.load(); 
return store;
```

}

And here is how i place the comboBox into the items of Ext.form.Panel :

```
var store = createComboBox();
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
bla bla 
items : [
 {
     xtype : 'combo', 
     store : 'store', 
     name : 'combobox', 
     fieldLabel : 'Select ', 
     displayField : 'sourceName', 
     queryMode : 'local'
 }
]
)};
```

Can you explain me why is that does not work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your store's proxy has a type defined of `'memory'`  Which as defined in the [sencha docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Memory):

> In-memory proxy. This proxy simply uses a local variable for data
>   storage/retrieval,

You will probably need to setup the type of proxy as `ajax` or `jsonp` and make sure the url to the specified service is correct.

Comment: Ok, so i changed the proxy's type as 'ajax' and modified the URL (which i know is correct). 


So i have to place the method used and/or the url in a specific place in the code ? 

Oh yes, the servlet is never used, why ?

Comment: I'm not familar with java applets but if there is a specific method it probably needs to be provided in the `url` or in the `extraParams:[]` array of the proxy.  [Here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/weeksdev/8149579#file-model-js) of an example model that i use with the proxy info required (you can use this proxy info in the jsonstore you are creating) https://gist.github.com/weeksdev/8149579#file-model-js

Comment: It works, thank you :)

I now have my Json like this : {"data":["Polo","BMW"],"success":true}

Do you knwo how can i use it to populate my combobox ?

Comment: Yeah, there are a couple of ways to do that.  Are you looking for an inline or mvc solution? [Here](http://try.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/docs/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.2/viewer.html) is an example from extjs to get you started.

Comment: Sure, i did that but it's a static combobox. I found a solution by modifying my JSON so that it look like this : {"data":["source":"polo", "source":"bmx"],"success":"true"} And it is work ! Thank you for your help :)